# How can I get the value of a dynamically created checkbox when the submit button is clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I have a asp.net page that has two controls on it, A placeholder and a submit button. During the Page_Load I create a checklist of tasks dynamically. Each row consists of a description, link to a tutorial, and a checkbox. All of the information in the row is kept in a database. If the database says the task has been checked, the code sets the checked property to true. The problem I'm having is that when the submit button is clicked I cannot find what the value is of the checked property for all of the checkboxes on the page(about 23 total).

Here is the code to create the checkboxes...

```
checkbox = new CheckBox();
phChecklist.Controls.Add(checkbox);

if (item.Attributes.Contains("ree_completed"))
checkbox.Checked = (bool)item.Attributes["ree_completed"];

checkbox.EnableViewState = true;
checkbox.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;

checkboxId = "checkbox" + (string)item.Attributes["ree_sectionnumber"].ToString() + (string)item.Attributes["ree_sequencenumber"].ToString();
checkbox.ID = checkboxId;
```

Here is the code to try and find the value of the checkbox...

```
foreach (Entity item in checklistCollection.Entities)
{
    checkboxId = "checkbox" + (string)item.Attributes["ree_sectionnumber"].ToString() + (string)item.Attributes["ree_sequencenumber"].ToString();

    itemChecked = (bool)ViewState[checkboxId];

    if (itemChecked == "true")
        ** update database **

     //CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)phchecklist.FindControl(checkboxId);
}
```

I think I've read every post on this subject and have tried most of them. I have also read about the ViewState but the suggestions that I have read about have not worked. As you can see I also tried finding the checkbox in the controls collection by the id and that also did not work.

I do not recreate the checkboxes when posting back to the page. Some posts mention that you have to recreate the controls but when I tried to do that I received an error message saying it was a duplicate id. The other reason I would prefer not to have to recreate the page is the performance hit. The database is in a Microsoft Dynamic CRM database that is remote.

How do I retain the value of checked property across a post back?

**UPDATE:** I changed my logic around and fixed the duplicate id error. The page will now recreate all of the controls during the post back. I still cannot find the value of any of the checkbox controls when the submit button is clicked.

Gary

Comment: You certainly need to create your controls during the Init event, Load is too late. Check out the [asp.Net page life's cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an ID for the checkbox control when you create it.  Since you are creating multiple checkboxes; one for each row in the database ... you need to add the unique row identifier to the ID.  So you need to build the checkbox ID from the row ID (usually the IDENTITY).  Example: ">

Then on postback while you are post-processing each row in the table, you can query the request for that specific key value pair.  Something similar to this:

foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
    Response["chk_" + dr("ID")];

Comment: I do provide a unique id for each checkbox...checkboxId = "checkbox" + (string)item.Attributes["ree_sectionnumber"].ToString() + (string)item.Attributes["ree_sequencenumber"].ToString();. What I end up with is checkbox11,checkbox12, etc.

Comment: Problem with that might be when you are post-processing ... how do you know which key value pair to get from the Response? The "chk_" + dr("ID")] needs to be something that you can build from the data that is available at hand during the post-processing.

Comment: The rows are built from the CRM database and the id is also built from the same information. That information doesn't change from the initial creation to the post back so the id will remain that same.

Answer (score 0):

Use Page Init as opossed to page_Load event. As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx "Use this event to read or initialize control properties"

Comment: I switched the creation of the controls to page_init and I still cannot find them in the viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

In case for that to work you need to add an event handler to dynamically added controls
in your case

```
checkbox = new CheckBox();
phChecklist.Controls.Add(checkbox);
checkbox.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
```

and then what you need to do in the method

```
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, you certainly need to create your controls during the Init event, Load is too late. Check out the [asp.Net page life's cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for details.

On a side note, you might want to let ASP.NET handle the controls's ID. You say you need to keep some value in order to get back to the database, you can [wrap your checkboxes in a table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bewx260%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). You will then be able to iterate through your controls without having to guess their names.

For instance, if your row has a HiddenField followed by your actual CheckBox:

```
//Please call me during Init
protected void createTheControls() { 
    TableRow tr;
    TableCell td;
    CheckBox cb;
    HiddenField section, sequence;

    foreach (Object item in someList)
    {
        section = new HiddenField();
        section.Value = item.Attributes["ree_sectionnumber"].ToString();

        sequence = new HiddenField;
        sequence.Value = item.Attributes["ree_sequencenumber"].ToString();

        cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.ID = String.Concat("checkbox", (String)sequence.Value);
        if (item.Attributes.Contains("ree_completed"))
            cb.Checked = (bool)item.Attributes["ree_completed"];

            td = new TableCell();
            td.Controls.Add(section);
            td.Controls.Add(sequence);
            td.Controls.Add(cb);

            tr = new TableRow();
            tr.Cells.Add(td);
        }
    }

protected void readTheControls()
{
    foreach (TableRow tr in myTable.Rows)
    {
        HiddenField section = (HiddenField)tr.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        HiddenField sequence = (HiddenField)tr.Cells[0].Controls[1];
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)tr.Cells[0].Controls[2];
    }
}
```

I notice you try to use the ViewState explicitly, which I believe is not going to be of any help here. The solution above may look cumbersome, but it will ensure you dont need to mess with ID's when fetching the controls.

Here's a [thorough explanation from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx), and here are a [few short and sweet SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807928/when-do-i-need-to-use-viewstate) explaining ViewState's purpose.

Comment: I can't have asp.net choose the id because I need to reference the value back to the db. Also I changed the code so the controls are created during page_init and I still cannot find them in the viewstate.

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Covered ViewState, which I believe should not be used explicitly here, and suggested a new way to generate your control which gets rid of the static client ID's and ViewState.